# Button doesn't trigger a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have the following code inside a `TemplateField` of `DetailsView`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" /></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Clicking `btn1` doesn't cause a postback and `btn1_Click` is never reached, but triggers all validators on page.

Changing `txt1` causes a postback and the method is reached as expected.

Why isn't there a postback on Button Click?

I tried adding `AutoPostBack="True"` to `btn1` and adding the `Click` event as an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` of the `UpdatePanel`. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that clicking on button doesn't causes the postback? Have you added a `ScriptManager` tag before your `UpdatePanel`. Your design code should look like

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager><asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="btn1_Click" /></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Yes, I have the `ScriptManager`.
I've put breakpoints in `Page_Load`, that's how I know there is no postback for the `Button`